# Python - Finding substrings at different parts of a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a string where I am searching for two substrings. I want the match to be true if both are found and false if both are not found. I also want the match to be false if the strings are both found but both are found on the same indexes. So I need both to be found but on different instances of the string.

For example if I have a string "23121172" and I am looking for both "2117" and "117", both substrings are found. But I want to test if the matches are matching on the same characters.

```
SearchList=["2117","117"]

line = "23121172"

if (all (x in line for x in SearchList)):
    print("Found")
else:
    print("Not Found")
```

So a line of "23121172" should print "Not Found" and a line of "2117 117" should print "Found"

Comment: @GregglePeggle You mean that matches should be nonoverlapping, did you?

Comment: "So a line of "23121172" should print "Not Found" and a line of "2117 117" should print "Found"", That's wrong, and makes no sense. `SearchList` is the list of items to search for, but you've gotten it confused with `line`. If you set `line` to either of those values it would still print `"Found"`, because `SearchList` contains both substrings.

Comment: As for this part: "I also want the match to be false if the strings are both found but both are found on the same indexes." - what you want to do here is use `.find` on the string to get the index, and then cut the match string out of the main string and continue.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then this code can help you:

```
for substr in sorted(SearchList, reverse=True):
    if substr in line:
        line = line.replace(substr, '')
    else:
        print("Not Found")
        break
else:
    print("Found")
```

Just keep in mind that the code modifies the `line`, so if you still need it, create a copy first

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex lib from python.

Ex.

```
import re
SearchList=["2117","117"]

line = "23121172"
for pattern in SearchList:
    if re.search(pattern, line):
        print('Found match',pattern)
    else:
        print('no match')
```